# Java class to read a zoo.cfg using Apache Zoo Keeper

Tags: java, apache, io, apache-zookeeper

I've been working with apache zookeeper and I've been asked to read the zoo.cfg which contains the properties:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181

server.1=192.168.100.125:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.3.41:2888:3888
```

I've been looking for a class of the framework (org.apache.zookeeper...) but I didn't found anything, I googled some information but I found something related with some classes of Hadoop that are not included in the jar I'm using and I'm not allowed to add other library. In the code I've been given I see:

```
 System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","conf/zoo.conf");
```

I was planning to read it from the System properties, but I don't know if it would be a good practice. What would you recommend? Or any suggestion please?

Thanks in advance for your help. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that I found a class inside this link https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/xref/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/zookeeper/ZKConfig.html

But it is not included in the basic zookeeper libraries since it is from hadoop (previous releases). Nevertheless, I managed to simulate the behavior of this class I found, but it gave me some errors. So I found easier to implement my own auxiliary class and read a custom file I prepared with the data of the servers (ip) and the port.

Thanks for your comments and answers. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and load the **zoo.cfg** file into it. The distinct values would be represented as Strings. The [Java Configuration API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) would be more sophisticated, but would require 2 or three extra libraries to be included.

Regards, Christian

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've already implemented that before, the purpose of my question is to know if there is a class in the zookeeper library that achieve the functionality without using the Properties stuff and the props.load(InputStream...), etc. I've been looking for this class but it seemed to be in a jar of Hadoop which is not anymore in zookeeper latest release. Thanks for your answer.